# Add Text at behind every line of JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea

I am creating a `Java` program with `Java Swing` to make my own link.

I had make a `JTextArea` for user to text and the system will automatically create a link.

**For example:** 
The user input follows in the `JTextArea` box

```
Good Day
I am so happy
```

Then the system will automatically create a link
`https://MyWebsites.com/content=Good Day%0AI am so happy/`

**Which means that the system will automatically adding `%0A` at every line return.**

I would like to know how can I adding `%0A` at the every line.

I am thinking of two ways to solve.
1: **Edit contents of `JTextArea`**
The `%0A` will directly added in the `JTextArea`.
2. **Adding when get String**
The content will **NOT** be affected, it will only be added when getting data from `JTextArea`.

(Advance)
If possible, the system should first check every line, if there are `%0A` on that line before adding it.

Comment: Better to add a conversation step which takes the text from the text area and generates the link

Comment: You probably want `new URI("https", "MyWebSites.com", "/content=" + textArea.getText() + "/", null)`.  And yes, the %20 sequences are supposed to be there;  space characters, just like newlines, are not permitted in URIs.

Comment: @VGR I don't only want to create URI, but to adding %0A directly at every lines end.

Comment: Try printing out that URI.  Its string form should be what you want.